# :last-child applying styles to all elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, flexbox

I am trying to create a container tab.

I want to apply a **`border-right`** to each element except my last **`li a`** child but the selector `:last-child` applies it to the whole list.

I want to remove the `border-right` of the last **`li a`**

See the image:

[image]

But this happens

```css
div#tabs {
  width: 100%;
}
ul.tab {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
ul.tab li {
  width: 100%;
}
ul.tab li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: solid 1px #CCC;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}
ul.tab li a:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:500px; margin:auto;">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul class="tab">
      <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

The selector you're using – `:last-child` – applies to siblings (i.e., elements having the same parent).

Each `a` in your code is an only child. So `:last-child` applies to all of them (and so would `:first-child`, `:only-child`, `:first-of-type`, and a few other [structural pseudo-classes](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#structural-pseudos)).

Consider applying the `:last-child` to the `li` instead.

Instead of this:

```
ul.tab li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: solid 1px #CCC;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}

ul.tab li a:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

Try this:

```
ul.tab li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}

ul.tab li:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: solid 1px #CCC;
}
```

```css
div#tabs {
  width: 100%;
}
ul.tab {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
ul.tab li {
  width: 100%;
}
ul.tab li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}
ul.tab li:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: solid 1px #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:500px; margin:auto;">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul class="tab">
      <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

> [**6.6.5.7. `:last-child`
>   pseudo-class**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#last-child-pseudo)
>
> Same as `:nth-last-child(1)`. The `:last-child` pseudo-class
>   represents an element that is the last child of some other element.

**By the way...**

Here's a simpler overall solution:

```
li + li {
   border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```css
div#tabs {
  width: 100%;
}
ul.tab {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
ul.tab li {
  width: 100%;
}
ul.tab li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}
ul.tab li + li {
  border-left: solid 1px #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:500px; margin:auto;">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul class="tab">
      <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have only one `<a>` in each `<li>` so you have to select last `<li>` and after that select the child which is `<a>`.

Just try like this `ul.tab li:last-child a`

```
div#tabs {
  width: 100%;
}
ul.tab {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
ul.tab li {
  width: 100%;
}
ul.tab li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: solid 1px #CCC;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}
ul.tab li:last-child a {
  border-right: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uyk2ro7w/